# How to compile windows binary on OSX

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, mingw, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I did a C# project on my Mac using Xamarin Studio. I need the binary to run on Windows. Right now it's using a gcc compiler. How do I get a Windows binary out of this? (Pretty sure I need to use mingw)

Comment: gcc does not compile C# code, so you're missing a part of the story that you didn't tell us. `Right now it's using a gcc compiler` -> what is **it** in that sentence?

Comment: Ok, so in my Xamarin IDE, under Preferences, the C compiler is gcc.  I just assumed that C# compiled to C or something (you know what happens when you ASS-U-ME.)  My question is -- how do I get a Windows binary from this IDE?

Comment: No, C# is compiled to CIL, which then you need to run via a runtime (in the case of Mono), or just double-clicking the file (if you're on Windows, as the default action for the latter is launching the .NET runtime). WalrusTheCat's solution should be your solution then, and you cannot reply to him with `it doesn't work`, you need to give more details about **how** it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin Studio builds the `exe`/`dll` for you automatically.
In your projects directory E.G. `/Users/ashleymedway/Projects/TEST/TEST`.
Browse to `Build/Debug` or `Build/Release`  depending on your configuration profile.
You will see the complied app/library. E.G `Test.exe`
The executable found here for a test console app ran fine in Windows 8 for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Because Windows Phone apps can only be developed on Windows, it is
>   impossible to develop for all three platforms on the same operating
>   system

http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/part_1_-_understanding_the_xamarin_mobile_platform/

Comment: definitely seems to imply that it's not possible to compile a Windows binary on OSX, but this could be a problem specific to Windows phone app development?